# How to read OData v4 endpoint with odatajs?

Tags: odata, datajs, olingo

I'm trying to read simple OData v4 endpoint with Olingo OData Client for JavaScript (odatajs).

Olingo odatajs webpage says:

> You may also use the documentation and the samples from the datajs library because the features and API are similar.

So I tried to read OData endpoint with this piece of code:

```
odatajs.read(uri, function (data) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(data));
  }, function (err) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(err));
});
```

But the code gives this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

With jquery/ajax it always calls error function, but you can see the response with fiddler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is an test case from odatajs git repository, hope it is helpful:

```
var headers = { "Content-Type": "application/json", Accept: "application/json" };
var request = {
    requestUri: "http://<wwww bla bla .com>/endpoints/FoodStoreDataServiceV4.svc/Foods",
    method: "GET",
    headers: headers,
    data: null
};


odatajs.oData.request(request, function (data, response) {
    if ((response.statusCode == '200') &&
        (response.body.indexOf('}', response.body.length - 1) == response.body.length - 1) &&
        response.headers['Content-Type'] == "application/json;odata.metadata=minimal;odata.streaming=true;IEEE754Compatible=false;charset=utf-8") {
        document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML += ("<div>odatajs V4 testing pass!</div>");
    } else {
        document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML += ("<div>odatajs V4 testing failed.</div>");
    }
}, function (err) {
    document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML += ("<div>odatajs V4 testing failed.</div>");
});
```